# Iterating rows and fill dataframe

Tags: pandas

I would like to add values to another dataframe, but have the Problem that I need to match GDP column with DestGDP column. An example shows what I am aiming for.
Existing DataFarme:

```
Place    Year  GDP   Pop
Paris   2015   10    15
Paris   2016   10    20
Paris   2017   12    22
Tokio   2015   15    23
Tokio   2016   18    26
Tokio   2017   20    30
```

The DataFrame is existing I just need to fill in the values in DestGDP,OrigGDP,DestPOP,OrigPOP from the DataFarem above.

```
Year  OrigPlace DestPlace   DestGDP OrigGDP DestPOP OrigPop
2015    Paris     Tokio       15      10       23     15
2016    Paris     Tokio

 List = ['DestGDP,'OrigGDP','DestPOP','OrigPop']
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What rule determines which is OrigPlace and which is DestPlace. Is it always Paris, Tokyo, respectively?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The secodn dataframe is completely given it just needs to be filled with values. There are more OrigPlace and DestPlaces.

Comment: My first idea would be pivot... I can't imagine from scratch, how to do it, but maybe you have ideas about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

```
x = df.groupby(['Year','Place'])['GDP','Pop'].apply(lambda g: g.values.tolist()[0]).to_dict()
```

**Result:**

```
{(2015, 'Paris'): [10, 15],
 (2015, 'Tokio'): [15, 23],
 (2016, 'Paris'): [10, 20],
 (2016, 'Tokio'): [18, 26],
 (2017, 'Paris'): [12, 22],
 (2017, 'Tokio'): [20, 30]}
```

You can access the result by :

```
x[2015,'Paris']
```

**Output:**

```
[10, 15]
```

Write your fill_func()

```
df1 = df1.apply(lambda y: fill_func(y), axis = 1)


def fill_func(y):
    y['OrigGDP', 'DestGDP'] = x[(y['Year'],y['OrigPlace'])]
    y['OrigPop','DestPOP'] = x[(y['Year'],y['DestPlace'])]
    return y
```

---

**Result:**

```
    Year    OrigPlace   DestPlace   DestGDP OrigGDP DestPOP OrigPop
0   2015    Paris       Tokio       15      10      23      15
1   2016    Paris       Tokio       20      10      26      18
```

## Edit:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Year', 'Place'])
# df['col'] = 'place' + (df2.groupby('Year').Place.cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
labels = df.groupby(['Year', 'Place'])[cols].apply(lambda g: g.values.tolist()[0]).groupby('Year').apply(lambda g: reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,g))

print(labels)
```

---

```
Year
2015    [10, 15, 15, 23]
2016    [10, 20, 18, 26]
2017    [12, 22, 20, 30]
dtype: object
```

---

```
Lst = ['OrigGDP','DestGDP', 'OrigPop', 'DestPOP']
```

---

```
fill_dict = labels.to_dict()
print(fill_dict)
df1[Lst] = df1['Year'].apply(lambda x: list(fill_dict[x])).values.tolist()
df1
```

**Result:**

```
    Year    OrigPlace   DestPlace   DestGDP OrigGDP DestPOP OrigPop
0   2015    Paris       Tokio       15      10      23      15
1   2016    Paris       Tokio       20      10      26      18
```

Comment: That is excelletn, how do I make that dynamiccaly thaht it works for all more column dynamiccaly (Above defined as list)

Comment: Thank you. I see this just works for the one dest orig pair. But the DatFrame consits of more. It is also Paris Peking for example. I was not able to extend it that it adds the valeus also for other Orig Dest places.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, assuming the first table is df and the latter table is dst_df.

```
for index, row in dst_df.iterrows():
    orig_row = df.loc[(df['Year'] == row['Year']) & (df['Place'] == row['OrigPlace'])]
    dst_row = df.loc[(df['Year'] == row['Year']) & (df['Place'] == row['DestPlace'])]
    dst_df['OrigGDP'].iat[index] = orig_row['GDP'].iat[0]
    dst_df['OrigPop'].iat[index] = orig_row['Pop'].iat[0]
    dst_df['DestGDP'].iat[index] = dst_row['GDP'].iat[0]
    dst_df['DestPop'].iat[index] = dst_row['Pop'].iat[0]
```

result

```
   Year OrigPlace DestPlace DestGDP OrigGDP DestPop OrigPop
0  2015     Paris     Tokyo      15      10      23      15
1  2016     Paris     Tokyo      18      10      26      20
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an example of a very efficient programming, but something straightforward. Gets all the possible combinations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Place', 'Year', 'GDP', 'Pop'], data=[['Paris', 2015, 10, 15],
                                                                 ['Paris', 2016, 10, 20],
                                                                 ['Paris', 2017, 12, 22],
                                                                 ['Tokio', 2015, 15, 23],
                                                                 ['Tokio', 2016, 18, 26],
                                                                 ['Tokio', 2017, 20, 30]])
df.sort_values(['Place', 'Year'], inplace=True)

chunks = []
for year, gr_year in df.groupby('Year'):
    nplaces = gr_year['Place'].nunique()
    df_dest: pd.DataFrame = pd.concat([gr_year] * nplaces, ignore_index=True)
    chunks.append(df_dest.merge(df_dest.sort_values('Place'), on='Year', how='left'))

def renamer(x):
    if x.endswith('_x'):
        return f'Orig{x[:-2]}'
    elif x.endswith('_y'):
        return f'Dest{x[:-2]}'
    else:
        return x

res = pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True).rename(columns=renamer).query(
    'OrigPlace != DestPlace').drop_duplicates(['OrigPlace', 'DestPlace', 'Year'])
```